# Do I require a from to submit input type=image for a jQuery type form submission

Tags: php, jquery

I have two images, that I am using their value to insert into a db table.  Do I Require a form or can I do without one.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="save.php"><input type="image" src="images/test.png" border="0" id="star_image" value="<? echo $some_value; ?>" /></form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="save.php"><input type="image" src="images/test1.png" border="0" id="star_image1" value="<? echo $some_value1; ?>1" /></form
```

Would the above trigger the below jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#form1').ajaxForm({});
$('#form2').ajaxForm({});

});
```

-----------------------------save.php--

```
insert into table (field) values('value')

.
.
.
.
```

And I want to submit the form using jQuery **only**

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Err. You've made significant changes to the question. It looks like the best approach is to insert the data when the page loads (rather then loading the page, then trying to use JavaScript to automatically make a request to the server that submits forms without user intervention in order to get data from controls designed purely for user intervention. (And jQuery still doesn't have an ajaxForm method as far as I can tell)

Comment: Not Err. I just did what I wrote above, its perfectly possible

Comment: Please link to the jQuery documentation for Ajax form then.

Comment: There is nothing more to what I have written above
what type of documentation are you talking about?

Comment: An API reference for instance.

Comment: And why are you saying "No, it is possible". I never said it wasn't. I just implied that it was an unnecessarily and hideously overcomplicated, unreliable approach.

Comment: @david
my objective is to use jQuery and have the two forms submitted as a toggle.  I achieved the same.

Please be clear on what API reference, I am working on an application which should be ready soon, and available for general usage.

Comment: If the tools used are described in the objective, it is a badly designed objective. I have no idea what "the two forms submitted as a toggle" means. The API reference for ajaxForm, which you call, but doesn't appear to be part of jQuery, despite you claiming to want to use "jQuery only".

Comment: @david


okay let me rephrase the entire scenario 

1. I have two images which toggles colors on clicking
2. I need to insert /update on clicking
3. I have to use jQuery and jQuery forms


Hope this answers your doubts

Answer (score 1):

You either need a form or you need to fake it with JavaScript.

Faking it with JavaScript is more effort and violates [rule 2](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build), so effectively, yes, you need a form.

That said, `input type="image"` creates a server side image map. It is designed to submit co-ordinates. Don't trust that its value will be submitted. If you really want to use an image input as a regular submit button, then check that its `name.x` is submitted (and this requires giving them unique names).

hmm, I see you don't have names at all at present. You must have a name before an input can be a successful control.

Finally, for `input type="image"` the alt attribute is mandatory (although not expressed in a machine readable way in the DTD so a validator won't pick it up).

Comment: Assuming I give names then the code would it be like


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#image1').ajaxForm(function(){
});


});


Once the above jQuery is executed what happens? or is the above code wrong?

Comment: @Jean — an entire answer about why faking it with JavaScript is a bad idea and describing how to do it properly; and you ask for help with JavaScript libraries?! (That code would just error though, there is no element with that id and jQuery doesn't appear to have an ajaxForm method lurking in its API).

Comment: I am going to add some more code, please check the question again, in about a minute.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery (and ajax), you don't need any form, nor values for controls, just send the parameters to your server-side script.
But if you are using form to be submitted, then no, you can not submit images, common practice is to use hidden input fields instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on javascript, then NO, you don't need a `<form>`, since you'll probably bind the element to post a request with XHR, but for accessibility purposes, you should wrap it with a `<form>` element, to get it to work without javascript.

By the way, don't use a form is **NOT** *recommended* by the W3C, <s>and your page will not validate for the reason explained above</s>.

Comment: There is nothing invalid about having inputs outside a form. In most cases there is a whole lot of stupid, but it isn't forbidden by the DTD.

Comment: Infact, you have a nested form, done the, nested form too, works like a charm

Comment: No. A nested form IS invalid and the behavior for what happens with them is undefined, so using a nested form is doubly stupid.

Comment: the idea is to get the work done, no it is not a bad idea, but its possible
i cant seem to find the link